# MAX485 wrong data output

Tags: uart, serial, rs485

I want to convert USART signals to RS485 with the circuit below:
[image]

I log the data on the USART6_TX and 485A/485B at the same time, but the data on the output pins of the MAX485 is wrong and it's not similar to data on USART6_TX.
the DE/RE pin of the IC is connected to the GPIO pin of the microcontroller. the microcontroller pulls up the pin while transferring data.

I transmit the data every 3seconds. the picture below is captured from USART6_TX pin and this is the data I expect to see on RS485:
(this is in HEX mode)

[image]

but I get this on MAX485 output:

[image]

- I use USBtoRS485 converter to log the rs485 data.
- I've tried some MAX485 ICs to make sure the reason is not the IC itself.
- my microcontroller is STMH750
- I use buadrate 9600bps , no parity, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit
- the output of RS485 stops to work on buadrate 1200bps.

Would you please give me some solutions to find the reason and solve it?

Comment: If you're converting from UART (TTL signal on DI pin) to RS-485, you need to enable the driver. You currently have it disabled -- the DE pin is pulled low.

Comment: thanks @DaveTweed. the DE pin is pulled up by microcontroller pin

Comment: I receive the data but the data values are wrong

Comment: You need to add that information to your question, along with a lot more detail about the nature of the errors. It could be many things -- baud rate mismatch, something else driving the RS-485 lines, etc.

Comment: "the DE pin is pulled up by microcontroller pin": not in your diagram.  Could you make the diagram match your actual circuit?

Comment: I updated the question, please let me know if I missed somthing else here

Comment: "receive the data but the data values are wrong ": what do you see?  what are you expecting?  Do you get the same results at 1200baud?  Do you have an oscilloscope, that would be the best way to find out.  If not, try 1 baud.  You have to tell us what you do see otherwise we're just guessing!

Comment: @jonathanjo I updated the question again. I get nothing at the output when I change the buad rate to 1200bps. I do have an oscilloscope but I can monitor the USART signals only, and dont know how to monitor the rs485 signals via oscilloscope

Comment: The data you added about what is transmitted and what is received is helpful.  Is it the same device transmitting and receiving?

Comment: The ideal thing is to put your scope probes on pin 4 and pin 6 of the MAX485, to see `DI` and `A` (non inverting output).

Comment: @jonathanjo no, the transmitting device is my board with the STMH750 micro and the receiving device is a RS485toUSB converter which I conected to my laptop and monitor the received data through terminal

Comment: Look at signal on `DI` to check it's arriving at driver chip.  If it is, check `DE` is high during data.  If it is, check signal at `A`, should look the same.  If it is, check `B`, should look same, but inverted.  if possible check these signals at laptop end.  Did you connect the ground from yoru circuit to the laptop's adaptor?  Highly recommended to read Perrin's [Art and Science of RS-485](https://www2.htw-dresden.de/~huhle/ArtScienceRS485.pdf).

Comment: The RO is connected to UART TX. That can't be right, connecting two outputs together. Which means RI and RX are two inputs connected together.

Comment: As @jsutme says, got to connect input to output and vice versa!  Is the error on the circuit (for _certain_ won't work) or on the diagram?

Comment: In addition to the A & B pair, do you have a Ground wire connected between your circuit and the RS485-USB converter at your PC?

Comment: Your received data looks like you might have the A & B pins reversed. Did you try swapping them over?

Comment: hey guys thank you! your all suggestios solved my problem. 1- @Justme yes that was the point. I did connet the rx and tx of microcontroller to the wrong pins of max485. thank you
2- jonathanjo the circut and the diagram was both wrong. thank you
3- brhans after correcting the circuit, swapping the A and B got me the right data in the output. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TX and RX is swapped and the floating input receives noise.